# How to Calculate WebView Height in Android ?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-view

I am using multiple WebViews in one activity. I am setting WebView content by using

```
 webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

I am generating WebViews content runtime, setting font, images etc and loading it on WebViews.

As I am using multiple WebViews its overlapping on each others, "wrap_content" dosent working, but If I give specific height to layout and then add webview in that then all looks fine.

So I am trying to calculte webview height, I have used following method to calculate that

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Done! WebView Height "+ webView.getHeight(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
    }
```

I have tried with *webView.getHeight()* as well as with *webView.getMeasuredHeight()* both are returning zero.

How to calculate WebView height ?

Comment: Ever solved this one?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m_webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView webView, String url) {
                super.onPageFinished(webView, url);
                Log.e("ABC", findViewById(R.id.m_webView).getWidth(););
            }
        });
```

Comment: it doesn't works, its retunes "0" I have tried with  findViewById(R.id.m_webView).getWidth(); as well as with findViewById(R.id.m_webView).getMeasuredHeight(); both are "0".